# Images not displaying on site (or in view source) after uploading them with ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I've manually added the filtered Html option because it wasn't there with my drupal 7 installation. In the editor view I get the upload image option etc, and I am able to browse and insert images. However, after hitting save, the images aren't displayed on the site.

I am using IMCE file uploader.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text format needs to allow `<img>` tags, otherwise they will be stripped out by default.

For example, add `<img>` to the allowed tags here:

`admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html` > "*Limit allowed HTML tags*"

Alternatively, try the "*Full HTML*" text format, if available and applicable as it will allow images by default.